# Will summing features improve the Machine Learning models?

Tags: neural-network, feature-selection, mlp

Assuming that I have two features, `x` and `y` for an MLP model. I know that depending on the model, the multiplication of features can yield a better feature. For example, if `x` and `y` are the dimension of a rectangle, then the multiplication will give the area.

Assuming that `x` and `y` are the area of a room and a kitchen. `x+y` will be the total area of the apartment.

Is it recommended to create a new feature by adding features together for Machine Learning models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of model you are using the model might be able to create these type of new features by itself, but if you have this added domain knowledge it is definitely recommended to create them yourself. For more info on this topic have a look at [feature engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_engineering).